# (MouseClick versus Click events for a RichTextBox) Why did MouseClick stop working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, .net-4.0

I had a MouseClick event for a RichTextBox working in my code, and something I must have done caused it to stop working. (Perhaps by altering the selected text location via the code below). I have now gotten my code to function well by using the Click event instead. The MouseClick event is simply not firing anymore, but it used to work.

```
_Box.Select(selectionExecutePosition,selectionExecuteLength);
_Box.Focus();
```

the events in question:

```
this.richTextBox1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.richTextBox1_Clicked);
this.richTextBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.richTextBox1_Clicked);
```

I must have changed something unawares. Any guesses/thoughts as to what I might have accidentally changed?

Comment: Can you please show the code in your handlers?

Comment: I would, but debugging does not hit them at all.

Comment: It does not hit the `Click` handler as well?

Comment: My real issue is indeed solved by using the click handler. Sorry if that is not clear in the Original Question. It just bugs me that I do not understand why.

Comment: When you hook both `Click` and `MouseClick` to your handlers, does it work? When you hook only the `Click` event does it work? When you hook only the `MouseClick` event does it work?

Comment: Click works all the time with or without MouseClick. I figure I should just stick with one, but I did try it. MouseClick used to work by its self but it no longer works without Click.